# How to tell if a select list has nothing selected in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

How can I use JavaScript in IE 8 to differentiate between a select list with the first item selected, and one with nothing selected?

```
<select id="first">
    <option>John</option>
    <option>Paul</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
    <option selected="selected">George</option>
    <option>Pete</option>
</select>
```

Browsers render the first list with "John" apparently selected. In Chrome and Firefox, the option is not properly selected: a CSS selector won't find it, so I can tell that it's not selected. However, IE 8 does select it properly, so I can't tell that it wasn't selected.

Here's a fiddle, which verifies that I can tell the difference between the two cases in FF and Chrome but not in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/YvfpV/7/

Is there any way to distinguish the two cases in IE 8?

Comment: Actually, in FF and Chrome the `select.selectedIndex` _is_ set to 0, so the element actually is selected, but `option.selected` is _not_ set.  (The fiddle shows this.) This inconsistency is how I can tell that the element wasn't preselected. IE is being consistent, which I don't actually want in this case. Poor IE: even when it's right, it's wrong.

Comment: Basing logic on a browser quirk that may not even be consistent for different versions of the same browser isn't a good way to build a reliable system.

Comment: Incidentally, in Firefox 5.0 `select.selectedIndex == 0` and `firstOption.selected == true` by default, so your logic fails in that version of Firefox.

Comment: @RobG: good points, well made. So I take it that your answer to my original question is "no" then. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I was wrong before when I said that FF and Chrome don't set `option.selected` on the defaulted option: they do. But the difference is that even though `option.selected` is true, the CSS selector `option[selected]` doesn't match it. So this looks like a bug in FF and Chrome, plain and simple.

Comment: Not necessarily. The relationship between attributes and properties has some history - setting a property is only reflected in an attribute in IE and HTML5 (which is not a standard). Most browsers treat attributes and properties as separte things - setting the property doesn't modify the attribute. `option[selected]` should select option elements with the selected **attribute**. Whether it is set by setting the **property** to true or not is browser dependent.

Comment: Yes, it looks as if I was misled by jQuery! In FF and Chrome, `option.getAttribute("selected")` returns `null`, but `$(option).attr("selected")` returns `"selected"`. (I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvfpV/7/) to show this.) jQuery's attr/prop handling changed recently so I don't know whether this is a bug or a feature. :)

Comment: jQuery formerly tried to "normalize" attributes and properties, which was a bad idea because they are different things. Now I believe the *attr* method only deals with attributes. I avoid get/setAttribute (and jQuery) and always use DOM properties as they are consistent across browsers and much simpler to deal with in general.

Answer (score 2):

If no option is selected, the the select element's [selectedIndex](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-85676760) property will be -1.

However, if no option has the selected attribute (i.e. none are [preselected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1)), browsers may select one option by default. Therefore it is recommended that one option has the selected attribute so you know which one will be selected by default and there should never be a case where no options are selected.

You can't reliably determine if the user selected the option or just used the default, so don't base your logic on knowing that.

#### Edit

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <select id="sel0">
    <option>0
    <option>1
  </select>
  <button onclick="
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel0');
    alert('selectedIndex: ' + sel.selectedIndex +  // 0
          '\noptions[0].selected: ' + sel.options[0].selected); // true
    ">hey</button>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

In Firefox 5 and Chrome 14, the default state of the select is with selecteIndex == 0 and the first option's selected property == true. So the apparent logic in the OP doesn't hold for those versions of the nominated browsers.

Comment: Yes, it's not generally possible to do this in a standards-compliant way. But it *is* possible in FF and Chrome, and I wonder if it's also possible in IE 8.